# How can i set up workers in kubernetes (infrastructure questions)

Tags: kubernetes, worker

I'm using kubernetes and i would like to set up workers , one of my docker host an API using flask, i have an algorithm in another docker (same pod , i don't know if i should leave it in the same) and other scripts that are also in separated dockers.
i want to link all of these, when i receive a request on the API, call the other dockers depending on the request and get the return.

I don't know how to do that with multiple dockers and so kubernetes.

I'm using RQ library for python to parallelize until now but it was on Heroku without kubernetes (i'm migrating to azure at the moment) and i don't know how it manage it behind.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

follow the below reference and setup kubernetes cluster using kubeadm.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/

using 'kubeadm join' command you should be able to add worker nodes to the master.
above given link has steps to join the worker to master

Comment: Could i just use a minimal instance of flask with a different port , i could just call other docker using localhost and the corresponding port . is it a bad way ?

Comment: what if the docker container is crashed. you need an orchstrator such as kubernetes or docker swarm to handle the life cycle. regularly poll the container health if it doesnt respond then the orchestrator will restart the container/pod

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Azure, you can try exploring AKS. It works out of the box. You just need to configure kubectl and you will be good to go.

Regarding deploying multiple microservices(API), you can deploy each microservice as a separate k8s deployment using kubectl and expose them using a service. This way they can communicate with each other using exposed endpoints(API) or a message queue .

Here is a quick guide you can take help from : https://dzone.com/articles/quick-guide-to-microservices-with-kubernetes-sprin

Comment: Could i just use a minimal instance of flask with a different port , i could just call other docker using localhost and the corresponding port . is it a bad way ?

Answer (score 0):

Typically you should use only one container per pod. Multiple containers per pod are possible but are typically used for sidecars, not for additional APIs.

You expose your services using kubernetes services, no need to run everything on a different port if you don't want to.

A minimal setup for typicall webapi calls would look something like this (if you expose your API service as public LoadBalancer you don't necessarily need Ingress)

Client -> (Ingress) -> API service -> API deployment pod(s) -> internal services -> deployment pods.

You can access your internal services from within your cluster using http(s)://servicename[:custom-port]

On the other hand, if you simply use flask to forward API calls to other services, you might want to replace it with an Ingress Controller that does all the routing for you.

Comment: That's interesting , i'll check that .
For :You can access your internal services from within your cluster using http(s)://servicename[:custom-port]  I'm sorry but i'm not sure to understand. could you explain more please ?

Comment: Kubernetes uses an internal DNS service. Every service definition includes a name. To communicate with other services in your cluster from within a container, you can use these DNS names just like any other domain name. So if you want to access say "internal-service-1" on port 80 and retrieve "/api/values", you'd just do an HTTP request to http://internal-service-1/api/values from within your api gateway pod.

Comment: If by "workers" you mean pods that don't expose a http service but simply run in the background working on a queue (since you mention RQ), the architecture is almost the same with the exception of not directly communicating via HTTP inside your cluster but passing messages through a queue. Depending on your use case you can use Redis for that, but there are also other managed options on Azure like Event Hub and Service Bus.

Comment: But they must be in the same pod right ? for the background worker And for RQ for example i need to import the conn from another file which is in the same docker . Can i do it between two dockers ?

Comment: instead of sharing the configuration, duplicate it, or even better use env vars and/or secrets for configuration data. here's a walkthrough for your use case: http://louistiao.me/posts/walkthrough-deploying-a-flask-app-with-redis-queue-rq-workers-and-dashboard-using-kubernetes/